# corda 4 - Can a State belong to more than one Contract class

Tags: corda

We are building a POC using Corda 4 and Springboot web server.

The POC is running in DEV MODE in our local network using PostgreSQL as database

The CorDapp developed for POC has four nodes -

1. Provider Node (Node 1)
2. Consumer 1 Node  (Node 2)
3. Consumer 2 Node  (Node 3)
4. Notary Node

All the above nodes participate in a deal. A deal consists of three worflows -

1. Flow 1 : data flows from Node 1 to Node 2
2. Flow 2 : data flows from Node 2 to Node 1 and Node 3
3. Flow 3 : data flows from Node 3 to Node 1 and Node 2

When all the three flows are executed the deal is FINISHED.

Suppose "DEAL 1" is started and "Flow 1" and 'Flow 2" are executed. Also for "DEAL 1" assuming "IOUContract.class" is used.

Due to new requirements, contract changed and a new contract class file "IOUContractv2.class" was created.

Now the application has two contracts -

1. "IOUContract.class" --- Used by "DEAL 1"
2. "IOUContractv2.class" --- Will be used by new deals

When I am linking above contract classes to the "State" using "BelongsToContract" annotation, the compiler does not allow repeated use of the same annotation.

```
@BelongsToContract(IOUContract::class)
@BelongsToContract(IOUContractv2::class)
data class State(val iou: IOU,
                     val sender: Party,
                     val recipient: Party,
                     var recipient2: Party,
                     val state: WorkflowState = WorkflowState.NEW,
                     override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(iou.bndId.toString())) : LinearState, QueryableState {
```

Questions:

1. How can I make both contracts use the same state?
2. Is my method to use two contracts wrong?
3. Can an aplication have only one Contract?
4. How to finish the execution of old "Deals" that used old contracts?

Comment: there is documentation for contracts upgrades https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/contract-upgrade.html#upgrading-contracts

Answer (score 1):

To make sure "What you see is what I see", we have "states" in Corda. States evolve over time. This evolution is governed by a set of rules. These rules are written in a "contract". A state transition is always associated with one contract at any point of time. As you have mentioned, you may wish to change these rules. In this case, you have to do a contract upgrade as Alessandro rightly pointed out. Since you are using Corda 4, you can use implicit Signature Constraints to do the contract upgrade. Follow below steps to upgrade your contract.

1. Stop your node.
2. Sign the jar. By default, if you do not disable signing in Corda
   version 4, the jar is signed when you run the deployNodes task. Stop your node.
   Sign the jar. To externally sign the jar use the [jarsigner](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/cordapp-build-systems.html). By default, if you do not disable signing in Corda version 4, the jar is signed when you run the deployNodes task.
   Replace the old jar with this newly signed jar.
3. Replace the old jar with this newly signed jar.